# EXCEL Search Data and complete data in a Row

Tags: vba, excel

Good day guys! I would like to ask, I have this Macro code that I use in encoding data to another sheet in the excel

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim i, lastrow As Long
If ActiveSheet.Range("d6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("g6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("c9") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all fields!"
    Exit Sub
End If

lastrow = Sheets("database").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 9
Do While Cells(i, 3) <> "" And i < 29
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("g6") ' Date
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("d6") ' Ref
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 4) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) ' Code
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 5) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) ' Description
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 6) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5) ' U/M
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 7) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) ' Qty
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 8) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7) ' Price
        Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 9) = "IN" ' Transaction
        i = i + 1
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
Loop
MsgBox "Saved Succesfully!"
ThisWorkbook.Save
Call RoundedRectangle2_Click
End Sub
```

what I want to achieve is that there is already an initial data that has been encoded in the target sheet and the macro will just find it and will fill out the data on it's respective columns

Comment: How would the existing data be identified?  Is there an "id" column?

Comment: it is numbered, starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

Keep working in your code, you are missing:

1. Add `.Value` at the end of each Range like  `ActiveSheet.Range("g6").Value = ""` or  `Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("g6").Value`
2. I don't understand why are you using `i<29` I guess if 29 is the lastrow create a new variable before the while like `j = lastrow` and then in the while use `Cells(i, 3) <> "" And i < j`
3. Does your data need to compare an id or a field to put the right data or it is just to follow the colums order?